# JDBC transaction not getting rolled back - setAutoCommit(false)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, transactions, rollback

This is typical project structure, a DB connection is created once user login to application.

```
Login.java{

    Creating DB Connection

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, strUserDB, strPasswordDB);
    CustomSession customSession = new CustomSession();
    customSession.setConnectionDB(conn);
}

CustomSession.java{
    private Connection      conDBConnection;
    // getter, setter
}

SubmitAction{

method1(ActionMapping map,
            ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)

    Connection conDB = null;
    CustomSession customSession = null;

    AService aservice = null;
    BService bservice = null;
    CService cservice = null;

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    try{
            customSession = (Connection) session.getAttribute("customSession");
            conDB = objOFSession.getDBConnection();
            conDB.setAutoCommit(false);
            aservice = new AService(conDB);
            bservice = new BService(conDB);
            cservice = new CService(conDB);

            aservice.method2();
            bservice.method3();
            cservice.method4(); // Exception comes, and commit is never executed

            conn.commit();

    }catch(Exception e){
        conDB.rollback();
    }
```

Every service (*aservice, bservice, cservice) typically has not DB Connection and execute stored procedures.
SP's are like doing Select, update, insert operations.

```
query = conConnectionDB.prepareCall(strCommand);
        query.execute();
        query.close();
          if(errCode != 0){
            throw new Exception(errCode,errorDesc);
          }

}
```

**Problem**
I can see Stored Procedure return me error code other than 0, so it goes inside my if condition and throws exception. I am catching Exception and calling rollback(), but as i see none of the changes are rolled back. My transaction moves ahead.

Also i have verified SP's does not contain commit statements.

Neither in Java code commit statement is getting executed, since exception is thrown.

I have also set `AutoCommit(false)` in the starting.

Please let me know as how can i trouble shoot this further.

Comment: You check also SP's inner calls to functions for example have no commits?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your current code is just fragments, and not even valid Java in the form its shown. Also, what do you mean with _"I have also set AutoCommit(false) in the strating."_? What is _strating_? And why isn't it shown in your code?

Comment: @user7294900 yes verified all function calls as well, no commits

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `strating` was a typo, rectified it, i think i have provided the the solution, posting a example would be very tough.

Comment: Even with changing it to starting, it is unclear what you mean. If you can't provide a [mre] that demonstrates the wrong behaviour, how do you expect use to figure out what is wrong in your situation.

Comment: **Most probably you are calling some DDL, which is calling COMMIT implicitely**. The easiest way to troubleshoot such problems is to activate [10046 trace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/performing-application-tracing.html#GUID-246A5A52-E666-4DBC-BDF6-98B83260A7AD). You will see all statements called by the session.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Thanks i will look into this for sure, probably can help me out, thanks for the pointers.
So it means if any DDL statement is executed inside stored procedures, it will auto trigger whole DB connection commits
How about triggers, will they get triggered or only after commit.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber If i am creating some temp table, can that also cause commit implicitly?

Comment: Yup, `CREATE TABLE` performs a *commit* (in Oracle).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Can commit in some other table in stored procedure also trigger for other tables as well, while executing SP, for debug purpose i insert data in debug/error tables and just commit this, will this effect commits for other tables within that transaction.

Comment: You `COMMIT` a  *session*  not a *table*, i.e. **all chnages** are commited. If you want to restrict the scope for *logging* check [*autonomous transactions*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-4B7E30F5-61CB-4A94-B198-09E2706C4CA5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196611/discussion-between-ankur-singhal-and-marmite-bomber).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber For the baove 2 cases, error/debug `pragma autonomous_transaction;` is already inside SP's, so it should not effect the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/transactions.html#GUID-7690181F-8293-47B9-ADC1-905BD9C3AF57)

> A database transaction consists of ...
>
> ...
>
> One data definition language (DDL) statement

I.e. after issuing a DDL statement e.g. `CREATE TABLE` statement all changes *done before* are commited and the `ROLLBACK` has no effect on them.

Illustration example

```
SQL> insert into test(x) values(1);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> create table tmp (x number);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL>
SQL> select * from test;

         X
----------
         1
```